# Windows Batch, passing arguments with spaces

Tags: windows, batch-file, arguments

I'm busy writing a Windows batch script and I'm having some problem with arguments.

My batch script is the following

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: RETRIEVE ARGS WITH SPACES

set VAR01=%~1
set VAR02=%~2
set VAR03=%~3

:: CONFIRM IT WORKED

echo %VAR01%
echo %VAR02%
echo %VAR03%

endlocal

exit /b
```

And I am trying to pass it arguments that include spaces.

```
run_batch.bat "arg var 01" "arg var 02" "arg var 03"
```

But when it runs I am getting the output

```
arg var 01
ECHO is off
ECHO is off
```

Why is it only working correctly for the first argument and how can it be fixed?

*NOTE*

There was never anything wrong with the code, it seems there were invisible special characters that there causing issues. Must have been the text editor or something along those lines. How do I remove this question?

Comment: Because you're never setting VAR02 and VAR03!

Comment: sorry that was a typo

Comment: Without the typo it works as expected

Comment: I'm getting those Null echos

Comment: Please copy the script into a new file (from this page) and recheck it. It should work

Comment: How can you have a typo.  Just copy and paste your code directly into the question you are creating.  Shouldn't be any problems at all.  No need to use delayed expansion in your code.

Comment: @Squashman the code is inside a virtual machine so I can't copy it. Also the code is a bit more complicated so I only post summaries because people tend to get sidetracked by everything else in the code

Comment: @Trent, strange. I have no problems copying out of any of the half dozen VM's I use.

Comment: @Squashman how do you do that? (I use VirtualBox) When I copy from it and try to paste it acts as though the clipboard is empty

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: RETRIEVE ARGS WITH SPACES

set VAR01=%~1
set VAR02=%~2
set VAR03=%~3

:: CONFIRM IT WORKED

echo %VAR01%
echo %VAR02%
echo %VAR03%

endlocal

exit /b
```

The wrong part was:

```
set VAR01=%~1
set VAR01=%~2
set VAR01=%~3
```

but should be:

```
set VAR01=%~1
set VAR02=%~2
set VAR03=%~3
```

Comment: The typo was never in my version, it was just a typo in my question

Comment: @Trent Please accept this answer because it solves your problem

Comment: It seems the problem was related to invisible special characters created from the text editor

Comment: @ManuelTaber how do I close this question? or remove it?

Answer (score 0):

A small example script for your perusal.

```bat
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

REM EXIT IF NO ARGS RECEIVED
IF "%~1"=="" EXIT

REM SET MINIMUM NUMBER OF ARGS
SET "i=1"

REM RETRIEVE ALL ARGS
:ARGS
SET "VAR0%i%=%~1"
SHIFT
IF NOT "%~1"=="" (
    SET/A i+=1
    GOTO :ARGS
)

REM INFORM NUMBER OF ARGS
CLS
ECHO=THERE WERE %i% ARGS

REM CONFIRM IT WORKED
ECHO=
SET VAR0

REM ALTERNATIVE CONFIRMATION
ECHO=
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%i%) DO IF DEFINED VAR0%%A ECHO=!VAR0%%A!

TIMEOUT -1
ENDLOCAL
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there was no problem aside from a typo. A quite tricky way to show the args and put them to numbered vars I learned from DosTips.org (but can't find the exact link) is:

```
:: Expand-Args.cmd
@Echo off
Set Args=,1=%~1,2=%~2,3=%~3,4=%~4,5=%~5,6=%~6,7=%~7,8=%~8,9=%~9
Set "Args=%*%Args:,="&Set "Arg%"
Set Arg
```

The batch will have this output run with:
`Expand-Args one "2 2" three 4 five 6 "7 7" 8 9`

```
Arg1=one
Arg2=2 2
Arg3=three
Arg4=4
Arg5=five
Arg6=6
Arg7=7 7
Arg8=8
Arg9=9
Args=one "2 2" three 4 five 6 "7 7" 8 9
```

**Edit** To not interfere with content in double quotes the delimiter `comma` might be replaced with an uncommon char like ALT+0127